# call parameterised function on dynamic button click in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to call a parameterised function in PHP. I am using AJAX for that.

This is my dynamic button. I need to pass `$sub_id` to the `delet(sub_id)` function and perform there some SQL.

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='disable' value='Disable' onClick='delet($sub_id);'/></td>";
```

This is my script so far:

```
<script>
function delet(sub_id) {
    alert("sub ID = " + sub_id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/my_page',
        data: {
            ID: sub_id
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    });
}
</script>
```

and this is PHP function:

```
function delet($ID){
    echo $ID;
    //do sql stuff...
}
```

All the code is in one file and I am doing this in wordpress default template swentysixteen. so there is no .php extension to my page.

when I click on the dynamic button, I am getting **404 error** in url parameter of ajax. When I see console, the url link seems to be correct.

Please help me in this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, dont combine in your mind JS code and PHP code into one.

Please set in your mind that JS code is executes on Browser which is provided by server through PHP. PHP code executes on Server side and provide HTML code as output to client(browser). so JS variables and PHP variable have no any relationship directly or indirectly.

For your solution,

You have passed ID parameterusing GET by ajax. so in SErver side you will get passed data in `$_GET` variable so ID will get by `$_GET['ID']`

```
function delete($ID){
   echo $ID;
   //do sql stuff...
}
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="delete")
{
    if(isset($_GET['ID']) && !empty($_GET['ID']))
    {
       delete($_GET['ID']);
       echo "deleted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "ID not passed for delete record";
    }
    die(); // you stop execution of PHP after delete opration here
}
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
function delet(sub_id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/my_page',
        data: {
            action: 'delete',
            ID: sub_id
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but to call parameterised function, I need to use AJAX. and I don't know how ajax works

Comment: Is seems your JS/Ajax code looks good... but you can pass one more parameter in your ajax request for action...

Comment: ahhh.. in your html code keep `<input type="button"` not `<input type="submit"`, otherwise it submitting form

Comment: if your all code in same page then ajax url should be blank `url: '' `

Comment: Thanks, done all the changes you said, but still not. showing alert box- mywebsite says: and below that all code :(

Comment: "Data saved" message came.. but I can't get ID value

Comment: you are talking about save operation?

Comment: AJAX code executed successfully, but now how do I access that variable which was passed on onClick() of button

Comment: execution is not cimming to this point -  if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="delete")
{

Comment: I want to pass the ID to this function -  function delete($ID) and perform SQL